# I can't find climbing claws in terraria

Tags: terraria-console

Does any one else have trouble finding climbing claws?
I searched all over my world with no luck and tried multiple worlds i am on xbox one version .
I only find shoe spike but i need the claws so i can make master ninja gear.

Comment: I had several worlds without one of them (claws and shoes). just continue searhing

Answer (score 0):

The [Wiki states](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Climbing_Claws):

> Climbing Claws can be found in surface chests (including Water Chests), or in a Wooden Crate.

You will just have to keep searching.  There isn't much more to it.